# Type mismatch VBA

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch, mismatch

This works Lastrow = 8, but not 9 (Type mismatch)

If i remove `If Not (myarray = Empty) Then` it does not work for 8

What is the easiest way to solve this?

```
Public Function GetRowToWriteOn(ByVal SheetName As String, ByVal idnr As Integer) As Integer
    LastRow = (Sheets(SheetName).UsedRange.Rows.Count) + 1
    MsgBox (LastRow)
    myarray = Sheets(SheetName).Range("d8:d" & LastRow).Value
    If Not (myarray = Empty) Then
        For row = 1 To UBound(myarray, 1)
            If (myarray(row, 1) = idnr) Then
                GetRowToWriteOn = row
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End If
    GetRowToWriteOn = LastRow
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: What are the values of `LastRow` and `row`? Wondering if you are exceeding the limits of an integer.

Comment: oh sorry, it is actually Lastrow which is 8 and 9

Comment: @user1383120 I'm sorry, I don't know what that is. I'm a beginner in VBA-excel. Will it help if I do, or if I don't. I am extending existing code, so I can't make any changes that will affect the rest of the code.

Comment: Getting the Value of a single cell doesn't produce a variant array, just a "regular" value, so your code needs to adjust for that.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that since the type mismatch occurs. That is why I ask _how_ I can solve it? That was what I tried to do with "myarray = Empty"

Comment: What are you trying to test for there?  Do you want to check whether each value in the array is non-blank, or something else?

Comment: Option explicit forces you to assign a datatype to your variable. (Example dim iCnt as integer) It gives the compiler information so it can reserve storage space in memory; example a Long type will take more memory than an integer. Without declaring variables, the compiler needs more processing time to test the type of data stored, which is at the cost of performance. Also, it helps you avoiding typos when using your variables.

Comment: @user1383120 - Option explicit doesn't force you to assign a datatype, only to name the variable. By default it will end up as Variant, but that's no different from not having declared the variable before using it...

Comment: You are forced to assign the datatype variant, no? I should perhaps rather say that it "enforces the behaviour of assigning adequate datatypes". Indeed, undeclared variables stand equal to variant declarations. However, not declaring a variable using when using option explicit results in error, so it does actually force you to declare each variable with a Dim statement.

Comment: @user1383120 - The only thing it forces you to do is declare what your variable names are: at a minimum it prevents mistakes due to variable typos. Of course, while you're declaring your variables it makes sense to specify their type to prevent other types of errors.

Comment: Declaring a name is useless, there would be no reason to use option explicit from this point of view because the compiler will know the name anyway without declaration as well. As I said, using the dim statement without assigning datatype is equal to assigning a variant. So it forces you to declare a datatype whether variant is explicitly mentioned or not. Using option explicit and not to "dim" (declare) a variable results in error, so it actually forces the declaration.

Comment: @user1383120: yes you are right. It forces you to declare your variables as a specific data type; default being Variant. More about option explicit in this link http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/to-err-is-human/ POINT NO 2

Comment: There are 2 advantages of using Option Explicit: 1)It **forces** you to name your variables before preventing errors due to difficult-to-spot typos in your code ("indx" vs "idnx")   2) It **encourages** you to type your variables, which helps prevent you from trying to assign values of the wrong type. True, if you don't do this, the default is Variant (ie. same as an undeclared variable), but Option Explicit in no way **forces** you to assign a datatype: the fact that one gets assigned by default doesn't count! (since that behaviour is not influenced by including Option Explicit or not)

Comment: thank you for explaining, I finished with the script so I have no need for it, but it might help others. Also I want to do as little impact on the code as possible since I'm not the "owner" of that piece of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyArray is taking 2 different types, depending on the range given.
If you are looking at 1 cell, then it is a single variant (which can be tested if it is Empty)
If you are looking at 2 or more cells, then it becomes an array of variant, so you would have to test each cell.

`myarray = Sheets(SheetName).Range("d8:d8").Value` - myarray gets the value in d8
`myarray = Sheets(SheetName).Range("d8:d9").Value` - myarray(1,1) gets the value in d8, and myarray(2,1) gets the value in d9

to test, use:

```
if vartype(myarray)=vbArray then
    ' run through the array
else
    ' do single value stuff
endif
```

Comment: Looks like what I want, I'll check it out later today. 
Thanks!

Comment: Seems like myarray is not an vbarray, it gives type = 8204. I'll investigate further

Comment: I did it the easy way, comparing it with 8204 directly :) You led me the right way anyhow :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'll never get the `vbArray` value (8192) on its own. It always has the type of the variable added on. 8204 = `vbArray` (8192) + `vbVariant` (12)

Answer (score 1):

I feel like your code should look more like this

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetRowToWriteOn(ByVal SheetName As String, ByVal idnr As Integer) As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long, row As Long
    lastrow = (Sheets(SheetName).UsedRange.Rows.Count) + 1
    MsgBox (lastrow)
    Dim myarray() As Variant
    myarray = Sheets(SheetName).Range("d8:d" & lastrow).Value
    If Not (IsEmpty(myarray)) Then
        For row = 1 To UBound(myarray, 1)
            If (myarray(row, 1) = idnr) Then
                GetRowToWriteOn = row
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End If
    GetRowToWriteOn = lastrow
    Exit Function
End Function
```

BUT I also think there is another way to do what you want. A little simpler and used built in functions. I think I captured your intention here:

```
Dim RowToWriteOn As Long, SheetName As String, lastRow As Long

Dim rng As Range

SheetName = "Sheet1"
lastRow = (Sheets(SheetName).UsedRange.Rows.Count) + 1
Set rng = Sheets(SheetName).Range("d" & lastRow)
RowToWriteOn = rng.End(xlUp).row
```

Comment: Well you miss the id in your example, so It will not write on an already existing row

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function GetRowToWriteOn(ByVal SheetName As String, _
                                ByVal idnr As Integer) As Long    
    Dim lastRow As Long, f As Range
    lastRow = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    Set f = Sheets(SheetName).Range("D8:D" & lastRow).Find(what:=idnr, _
                                                      lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        GetRowToWriteOn = f.Row
    Else
        GetRowToWriteOn = lastRow + 1
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I managed with another (not as pretty as this) way, so I have not tested this, but it seems like it could work.

Answer (score 0):

```
myarray = Sheets(SheetName).Range("d8:d" & LastRow)
```

(without value)... 
And you can use: `if ubound(myArray) > 1 then ;..`

I think it could be as easy as this, no...?

Comment: I'm quite sure that you can load a range directly into an array and vice versa if they are both equally sized.

Comment: ubound(myarray) will generate an error if used on a single value

Comment: It's possible that ou need to set myArray multidimensional through the redim statement first => myArray(1 to something, 1 to 1) You'll need to check.